Creating Column of seats from a single line description in Google Sheets
we are booking a training and we are trying to convert a description of what seats we have into a columnn list so we can automatically allocate our students to a class.
Eg the the description of the seats description cell looks like:
Cell F5: TrainingRoom1/E 17-18 (2) , TrainingRoom1/J 21-24 (4) , TrainingRoom1/F 19-21 (3) , TrainingRoom1/H 21-24 (4) , TrainingRoom1/K 21-25 (5) , TrainingRoom1/N 21-24 (4) , TrainingRoom1/M 21-25 (5) , TrainingRoom1/P 23-25 (3)               
We want to turn this into a couple of columns that looks like:

ColumnA:Room ,
ColumnB:SeatNumber
ColumnC:Email (will be allocated later)

Results would look like:

TrainingRoom1 --- E17
TrainingRoom1 --- E18


Here's a possible solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
   data,WRAPROWS(SPLIT(F5,"/ (),-"),5),
   SPLIT(
     REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
       LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,
         INDEX(data,i,1)&"|"&INDEX(data,i,2)&
         SEQUENCE(INDEX(data,i,5),1,INDEX(data,i,3))))),"|")))


